# What's the location for the Gradle Home?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to import a project. For that, I downloaded a zip file and extracted it. 
I am trying to create this project but can't find the Gradle Home.

I have searched frantically but can't find the answer to my question.

PS. Kindly upload the screenshots also while answering...

Comment: Are you looking for windows or mac or linux?

Comment: I am on Windows

Comment: Does the project contain a ```gradle``` folder, ```gradlew``` and ```gradlew.bat```? Usually you should just use the gradle wrapper option while importing.